# rails create one lambda and use the same in multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lambda

I would like to **create one lambda** and use it in **multiple models**.

For example:

```
scope :get_belongs_to_patient, lambda { |patient_id| where(patient_id: patient_id).order(created_at: :desc) }
```

I should use this lambda in ten models (the same code). So, have any way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html). Here's a good [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20130712014326/http://blog.andywaite.com/2012/12/23/exploring-concerns-for-rails-4/) on them.

Name it "BelongsToPatient" or whatever makes sense to you.  You want to be describing all of the "things" that are belonging to `Patient`.

Example:

```
# app/models/concerns/belongs_to_patient.rb

require 'active_support/concern'

module BelongsToPatient
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    scope :get_belongs_to_patient, lambda { |patient_id| where(patient_id: patient_id).order(created_at: :desc) }
  end

end
```

Then, include the module in all of the models where you want to have the scope:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include BelongsToPatient
end
```

`MyModel` will now have access to your `:get_belongs_to_patient` scope.